# Output attributes from "Find Routes" tool

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, network-analyst

In the Output from "Find Routes", I see there are attributes like "Total_Meters", "Total_Kilometers" and "Total_Miles". What does these mean and how they are different from actual length of the route? In my output, the actual shape length of the route is different from these values shown in these columns. My output from "Find Routes" tool shows the shortest route between stops.

Answer (score 1):

First even though you have multiple "totals" I believe they should be equivalent, just in different units.

These "totals" are based on how the network dataset is configured to calculate this "cost".   For example the network dataset could be configure to get the "cost" simply from the length of the polylines, or it might come from some attribute on each polyline where the  value representing the distance (maybe from some other source).  There can be many ways to set up the cost.

Also to note the network dataset can be configured to add to the "cost", so a stop could have an "added cost" that is added to the total (it might represent stopping at a location to drop off a package or such), also there are scaled cost barriers, these can, for example, double the underlying cost of traversing a section of a road.

The "shape length" of your route is dependent upon the coordinate system\projection.  So if your output is in WGS84 the shape_length is in decimal degrees.  You could project that to get something in say meters ... but which projection you use will determine it how accurate it is to the real world.  Something like Web Mercator might not give a super accurate value where as State Plane might be closer to the real world value.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. Yes, all the multiple "totals" are equivalent in my results as well. I am finding the shortest routes between two points (origin and destination) on a rail network dataset. When I calculate the length of output shortest route using "Calculate Geometry", it gives a different value than the multiple "total" provide ("total" value are far smaller than calculated length). Still wondering why?The only impedence/cost value used in my network dataset is the length of the route. Time is mentioned in the network dataset properties but it is not assigned any evaluater.